# MySQL - Multiple inserts in different tables

Tags: mysql, insert

I have 3 tables: T1, T2 and T3

My goal is to insert some rows from T1 to T2 and for each inserted row to create a new entry in the Table T3 with the new inserted id that is autogenerated in table T2.

Example:

T1 has

```
id   name   email
1    n1    e1@a.com
```

And will copy in the T2

```
id   name   email
5    n1    e1@a.com
```

So my goal is here to insert also in the T3

```
id  T2.id
1   5
```

The insertion is done this way:

```
INSERT INTO T2 (name, email)
SELECT name, email
FROM T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * 
             FROM T2 
             WHERE T1.email=T2.email
             )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If insertion is done by email constraint then I think below query is nearer to your solution.

```
Insert into T3 (T1_id,T2_id)
( 
  Select T1.id, T2.id from T1 LEFT JOIN T2 on T1.email = T2.email 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS 
     (select * from T3 where T1.id = T3.T1_id or T2.id  = T3.T2_id)
 )
```